# Somewhere between Tomcat 7.0.73 and 7.0.92, AllowLinking stopped working

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have two servers running tomcat. One is version 7.0.73 and the other is 7.0.92. They both have allowlinking set to true, but while it works in 73 (in fact, since the default is true, it doesn't really even need to be set) the server running 92 errors out when faced with a symlink to a webapp. I've checked the changelogs and looked for it in the other xmls, but no joy.

Has anybody seen this kind of problem before, or know how to fix it?

Comment: Check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/574784/how-to-add-symbolic-link-as-webapp-to-webapps-in-tomcat-7-on-linux).

Comment: I appreciate it, but it doesn't pertain. I'm not using netbeans, and I can't set the docbase when the problem is that I need different webapps to reference different directories. And, obviously, allowlinking isn't working. :(

Comment: There are several other answers not just the netbeans one. Try to make your question a [MCVE] as expected by SO.

Comment: 1) Not using Netbeans.
2) Can't set docbase.
3) allowlinking doesn't work.
I think that covers the answers that question 574784 gives. If you know of another, I would appreciate it. I actually checked that answer before I asked here.

Comment: And unfortunately, my servers are in a secure environment, so it's difficult to give an example. I could type in the Catalina logs, if that would help.

Comment: As it is, it's almost impossible to help. Try checking permissions and selinux stuff.

Comment: Two things that you have left out of your question that would really help here: (1) what is your environment and (2) what is the error that you get?

Comment: 1) Centos7  -----
2) SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base <<path to symbolic link result>> does not exist or is not a readable directory
---
The path it shows leads to the resultant war file, not the link's name. Just FYI
---
And thank you both for your help.